# exchanging private key between service and iPhone app - digital signing

Tags: encryption, rsa, signature, keys, key-exchange

I need to do digital signing of my request data which will be sent to the server. My server sends distinct private keys to her clients after authentication and expects all responses to be digitally signed with those keys for next x days. In order to represent a private key instance in iOS it expects a `.p12` file with a password input.

Since the private keys change dynamically for every user, I can have a persistent certificate or `.p12` on my device to read the private keys. In that case, is it advised to send the `.p12` file as part of the JSON response in base 64 format over the wire after authentication, create a `.p12` file buffer and do message signing? Is this safe? Or is there any security vulnerability in this approach?

Comment: *No one* should be sending private keys over the wire. The correct way would be for the client to generate a key pair and do a certificate signing request to the server (e.g. PKCS10), or at the very least simply send its public key to the server (over an authenticated connection for both cases, of course).